# std::ifstream initialization with filename

Tags: c++, ifstream

I am using the following piece of code to check whether file is existing or not using `std::ifstream`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    if (std::ifstream("file.txt"))
    {
        std::cout << "File present\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Since I am not using any object for `std::ifstream`, how do I close the file? Or is it not required to call close?

Comment: The file is closed automatically (you are using a *temporary* object).

Comment: Unrelated comment, but don't rely on this for anything important. The only way to be sure there is a file is to open it and hold onto the handle. Because otherwise another program could remove the file after you checked it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually you are using unnamed temporary object of `std::ifstream`. It is not required to call `std::ifstream::close()`, as the object is being destroyed after usage, and it's destructor closes the file correctly.

To be more precise:

```
// Temporary object is not yet created here
if (std::ifstream("file.txt"))
{
    // Temporary object is already destroyed here
    std::cout << "File present\n";
}
// Or here
```

From [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream):

> (destructor)[virtual] (implicitly declared)
>
> destructs the basic_ifstream and the associated buffer, closes the file

Answer (score 1):

It's a temporary object so there's no need to close it because it closes automatically after you're done using it.
If you want to make sure you can always use `std::ifstream::is_open`
[Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/)'s a list of functions in ifstream